# Maven: Bind plugin default-cli to different phase

Tags: java, maven

It's relativly simple:
I have a plugin goal `tomcat7:run` which i run directly in Eclipse m2e (the full command would be `mvn tomcat7:run`). But it runs too early (on `process-classes` it think), skipping the test phase. I want it to run after the test phase when invoked via cli.

I tried to simply change default-cli phase to be `package` instead of `process-classes`, but this doesn't work (phase does not change to package):

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        ...
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <!-- Change phase, doesn't seem to change anything -->
        <execution>
            <id>default-cli</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>package</phase>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Running a default phase like `mvn package` and this execution

```
<execution>
    <id>default-run</id>
    <phase>package</phase>
</execution>
```

instead works but is not an option, because i don't want to execute this when creating a real package (this plugin starts up an embedded tomcat server). I'm considering profiles, but i think profiles where not made for this kind of problem.

Relevant log:

```
[INFO] >>> tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.3-SNAPSHOT:run (default-cli) > process-classes @ gmm >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- frontend-maven-plugin:0.0.26:gulp (gulp build) @ gmm ---
...
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ gmm ---
...
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ gmm ---
...
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.3-SNAPSHOT:run (default-cli) < process-classes @ gmm <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.3-SNAPSHOT:run (default-cli) @ gmm ---
... (tomcat7:run log output here) ...
```

Comment: What do you mean "it doesn't work"? What exactly is the command you are running, and the logs you're having?

Comment: It doesn't work means "the phase doesn't change". I added this information & relevant log to the question.

Comment: Okay but you haven't answered the rest of my questions: what exactly is the command you are running? It seems like, from your logs, it is getting executed twice?

Comment: Added. It's only executed after the last log line. I think it cannot be executed twice because it blocks the build thread when it gets executed (it starts an embedded server) and thus anythin that comes after it.

Comment: I also added code for how using default phase works.

Comment: The [documentation for the tomcat7:run goal](http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-trunk/tomcat7-maven-plugin/run-mojo.html) includes the line "Invokes the execution of the lifecycle phase process-classes prior to executing itself." I'm not sure if that can be changed dynamically. You might have to run `mvn test tomcat7:run` to get the behavior you seek.

Comment: But then i would have to compile twice, and compile time is already quite long (javascript / sass builds going on in frontend-maven-plugin)...

Comment: That's from my point of view a bug in tomcat7-maven-plugin:run goals which forks the life cycle. This should be changed....